# Delphi 7 - Fetch value from a website

Tags: delphi

let's see if yaw can help me out here,

Supposing there's a link: www.example.com/test.html

Upon opening, it would show either 0 or 1.

I need to fetch that value. I.e.:

```
if internet.value := 0 then ShowMessage('False') else ShowMessage('True');
```

It could be using indy components or winsockets, how would I go about this one?

Comment: Please add details about what you have done so far and where you are facing problems. This site helps you to code, not to provide you the full code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelphi%5D+download+http&submit=search

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelphi%5D+parse+html&submit=search - this probleam consists of two questions. They both were many times answered on SO

Comment: @Arioch, it depends on what is the content of a target resource. I only guessed in my answer that it's a plain text content (from *show either 0 or 1*) so I think it might be just a plain text file saved as a HTML file (not valid HTML though, but resolvable by browsers).

Comment: @TLama Well, until proved that topicstarter explicitly lies to server about file type, i'd assume the URL correctly designating file type. Also i expect that topicstarter might be trying to extract data from some existing page rather than implement his own server.

Comment: @Arioch, well, it seems my guess was right, but you're right, I'd expect a valid HTML file too (having a valid HTML head etc.), but you can also create a plain txt file, save it as HTML and your browser will resolve it as a text file, what seems to be the OP's case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about a plain text file containing just an integer value, you can use Indy for this e.g. this way. The following function returns True, when the page downloading succeeded and when the page contains an integer value, False otherwise. Please note, that I wrote it in browser so it's untested:

```
uses
  IdHTTP;

function TryWebContentToInt(const AURL: string; out AValue: Integer): Boolean;
var
  S: string;
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    IdHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
    try
      S := IdHTTP.Get(AURL);
      Result := TryStrToInt(S, AValue);
    except
      Result := False;
    end;       
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And the usage:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if TryWebContentToInt('http://example.com/page.html', I) then
    ShowMessage('Value: ' + IntToStr(I))
  else
    ShowMessage('Page downloading failed or it doesn''t contain an integer value!');
end;
```

Comment: This is spot on, I'm impressed. Thank you for the snippet.